# MATLAB: generating Eye Diagram of a time-domain signal

Tags: matlab, plot

I have a csv file of time signal. The data has been extracted from Cadence Virtusuo. I can simulate in Virtusuo and get the Eye Diagram of the signal over the 30ns period and using 500ps time step. Now I wanted to generate the same plot in MATLAB. But my MATLAB code doesn't generate same eye diagram as I see in the Virtusuo SImulator.

Can anyone help me to get the plot that I want to generate in MATLAB. [Here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/5ck4bnuqj9xsafa/Data.csv?dl=0) is the Data in csv and the desired eye diagram image from Cadence Virtusuo has been given. My MATLAB code is given also.

Desired Eye Diagram:
[image: Desired Eye Diagram]

MATLAB code:

```
% open data file
fid = fopen('Data.csv');

readData = textscan(fid,'%f %f','Headerlines',1,'Delimiter',',');

% Extract data from readData
xData = readData{1,1}(:,1);
yData = readData{1,2}(:,1);

eyediagram(yData,300,10e-10);
plottools
```

MATLAB Generated Plot:
[image: MATLAB Generated Plot]

Comment: Is there anyone can help me?

Comment: Is your problem with the data shown? or you just want to make it red on black?